# limit the selection of button from multiple button

Tags: javascript

I am making a ticket booking system. I want a user can only select 3/4 ticket maximum. I have group of button which are append by a javascript in columns for seat selection. Now I want to limit the selection of button selection from that group by user. that should be in javascript.
*I just started Practicing.*
*I am using laravel framework.*

```
<script>
var pages = 40;
var page1Buttons = $('#col1Buttons');
var page2Buttons = $('#col2Buttons');
var page3Buttons = $('#col3Buttons');
var page4Buttons = $('#col4Buttons');

for (var j=65; j<=75; j++){
    page1Buttons.append('<input class="btn btn-primary single_seat" name="options"  type="button" id="seat" value="' + String.fromCharCode(j) + '' + 1 + '"/>');
    page2Buttons.append('<input class="btn btn-primary single_seat" name="options"  type="button" id="seat" value="' + String.fromCharCode(j) + '' + 2 + '"/>');
    page3Buttons.append('<input class="btn btn-primary single_seat" name="options"  type="button" id="seat" value="' + String.fromCharCode(j) + '' + 3 + '"/>');
    page4Buttons.append('<input class="btn btn-primary single_seat" name="options"  type="button" id="seat" value="' + String.fromCharCode(j) + '' + 4 + '"/>');
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can you please put the example code you're working to your question here?

Comment: @AntiqTech post is edited with code sample.

Comment: thank you for the example code.  Can you explain the logic of limitation in more detail via example. It's not clear from the question.

Comment: @AntiqTech I am making a ticket booking system. I want a user can only select 3/4 ticket maximum. Thank you.

Comment: @FerozMahmudJames You didnt explained anything, you just repeated your question.

Comment: @FerozMahmudJames Hi again. I want you to explain how you will limit the selection when a user tries to select a seat. i.e. "when User selects a seats from 'group1' , all  the other buttons in all the other groups become disabled" etc.  We need the limitation logic so that we can comment your code. By the way, your example code only adds buttons in "div" elements (I think). So it not fully helpful to us either at the moment.

Comment: @AntiqTech. Thank you for your co-operation. I solved the problem.. Thank you Everyone.